# What is a proper way to initialize data store for static data in Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a model called "Category" in my app in GAE.

This model simply contains a name and it's parent category, and this won't be changed frequently after the website go online.

I'd like to know what is a better way to put these model instances in the beginning?

I now only know to execute (`category.put()`) in a webapp.RequestHandler by issuing a http request. But I suspect there is a proper way to do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [remote API](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/remote_api.html) to connect to your datastore in a shell and add data as required.

Or, if it's a huge amount, you could think about using the [bulk loader](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html) - but I suspect that the remote API will be more suitable.

Comment: Thanks! remote api seems powerful!